# Recent problems connecting Filter Web Part to list view's EMM field

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

This worked perfectly a month ago, but someone just showed me that all my pages built this way are now broken!

I have built pages on the premise of passing in a project name in the QueryString, grabbing that value in a QueryString Filter part, and using it to refine a list of Projects by connecting the filter to a Project Name field. The Project Name field is a Managed Metadata field, and this sort of filter worked perfectly up until very recently.

Now whenever I try this, I just get a page saying "Sorry, somehthing went wrong" and "An unexpected error has occurred." The filter works fine on its own (doesn't break the page), and the list view is also fine. If I don't pass in a value in the querystring, the page loads fine but without filtering. But when it tries to filter using the EMM field, I get this error.

I've done this for years now, on a number of pages across several different lists. Has anything changed with the Term Store or how it works?

Comment: Have you opened a ticket with Microsoft Support in your Office 365 Admin center? This sounds as if they may have broken something.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for adding an answer but I don't have enough of a rep (first post).

We have started seeing this issue as well, and like you I have been using this technique for years. All of a sudden the connected web parts display a correlation error and a message saying "Cannot complete this action. Please try again".

I've tried a number of sites, even created new structures and it doesn't seem to work.

Hope this is temporary and not a way of them saying that the Query String filter is dead!

EDIT: We logged an issue with MS and within a couple of days this issue was fixed within the Australian O365 world. Not sure if this issue was isolated or not.